# Does the EVM calculate the gas used for a transaction in real time?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price, gas-estimate

Does the EVM calculate the gas used to execute a transaction on the fly as opcodes are being executed? So if there's a branch in code whose conditional is  satisfied then additional gas is used to execute the block of opcodes that follow from that branch.

Comment: Yes, if you want to take a look to where it actually happens in go-ethereum : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/interpreter.go#L197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's two concepts that are relevant here: gasLimit and gasUsed.

When you send a transaction, you specify a gasLimit. This is 21,000 by default, but can be modified either manually or by the wallet. GasLimit is the total amount you (the sender) is willing to spend on the trasnaction.

GasUsed is the actual amount of gas spent to process the transaction. This is computed at runtime by the miner. As long as the gasUsed is less than the gasLimit, the transaction succeeds and the sender gets the remaining gas returned. If gasUsed goes over gasLimit, the transaction fails.

So yes, if a transaction logic branches and skips a bunch of opcodes, you will use less gas than if the logic went through the longer path.